# USB disabled when installing CentOS 5.8

Tags: usb, keyboard, centos, centos-5

My USB keyboard does not response when installing CentOS 5.8 with options "linux noprobe".
Given the fact that before installing from a burnt DVD, I once tried to install from a USB flash storage, it always prompts "Boot error...", I suspect the USB interface is disabled during CentOS installation.
Unfortunately, there is no PS/2 interface on my machine.
Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Why are you using noprobe?

Comment: @parkydr otherwise, the installation will be held at the screen "loading ata_piix driver..."